# Golang - text/template unit test to cover all the use-cases

Tags: go

I've the following example (similar of what we have in prod) "text/template" code which works OK, now I want to create a unit test for it that checks the function and also the `text/template` to see that I cover 100% of the code...

The problem here is how to do the **text/template** unit test which covers **all the cases**. I'm currently new to text/template and I want to make sure it's working as expected.

Please visit:
https://play.golang.org/p/203Al36Zigk

This is the template:

```
const tmpl = `#!/bin/bash
{{- range .File.Dependency}}
echo {{.EchoText}}
{{- range .Install}}
submitting {{.name}}
{{- end}}
{{.TypeCommand}}
{{end}}

{{- range $k, $v := .API}}
echo {{$k}}
submitting {{$v}}
{{end}}
`
```

Comment: https://github.com/stretchr/testify -> for Testing Use this Package ..

Answer (score 3):

You should setup a template_test file dedicated to testing the output of your template file.

For that, looking at the sources of the [golang `text/template` package](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) is always a good idea.

As an example (to be adapted to your case), you have [`src/text/template/example_test.go`](https://golang.org/src/text/template/example_test.go) which uses a classic [table-driven test](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests) approach:

```
package template_test

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
)

func ExampleTemplate() {
    // Define a template.
    const letter = `
Dear {{.Name}},
{{if .Attended}}
It was a pleasure to see you at the wedding.
{{- else}}
It is a shame you couldn't make it to the wedding.
{{- end}}
{{with .Gift -}}
Thank you for the lovely {{.}}.
{{end}}
Best wishes,
Josie
`

    // Prepare some data to insert into the template.
    type Recipient struct {
        Name, Gift string
        Attended   bool
    }
    var recipients = []Recipient{
        {"Aunt Mildred", "bone china tea set", true},
        {"Uncle John", "moleskin pants", false},
        {"Cousin Rodney", "", false},
    }

    // Create a new template and parse the letter into it.
    t := template.Must(template.New("letter").Parse(letter))

    // Execute the template for each recipient.
    for _, r := range recipients {
        err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, r)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("executing template:", err)
        }
    }

    // Output:
    // Dear Aunt Mildred,
    //
    // It was a pleasure to see you at the wedding.
    // Thank you for the lovely bone china tea set.
    //
    // Best wishes,
    // Josie
    //
    // Dear Uncle John,
    //
    // It is a shame you couldn't make it to the wedding.
    // Thank you for the lovely moleskin pants.
    //
    // Best wishes,
    // Josie
    //
    // Dear Cousin Rodney,
    //
    // It is a shame you couldn't make it to the wedding.
    //
    // Best wishes,
    // Josie
}
```

For the assertion part, look in [`src/text/template/multi_test.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/text/template/multi_test.go) which defines [`multiParseTest`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/text/template/multi_test.go#L21-L29) as a structure with a template, *and an expected result, which allows to do [assertions like](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/06b326054dc0cad03b7b848d8516a578dd8b559f/src/text/template/multi_test.go#L72-L81):

```
result := tmpl.Root.String()
if result != test.results[i] {
    t.Errorf("%s=(%q): got\n\t%v\nexpected\n\t%v", test.name, test.input, result, test.results[i])
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) , Im not sure that I fully understand it, how should I do the assertion ? can you please provide example in my context or close ?

Comment: @Ninawatcher Yes, that test covered only the execution, not the assertion checking the template output. I have edited the answer to add an example performing such an assertion. Again, this is very similar to hat is described in https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests: a list of inputs and outputs, with the assertion checking your program delivers the expected output from the list.

Comment: Neat use of `Example`. I had totally forgotten that examples run with `go test` https://blog.golang.org/examples

Comment: Hi, I didnt have much time to test it and I want to test it now. since we are running out of time ( for bounty) . can you please assist ? lets say the file logic is in file `genfile.go` and I've created file `genfile_test.go` , which logic from your example should be written in the test file can you give example ?

Comment: since if I use `func TestGenerate(t *testing.T) {
 
 
 result := tmpl.Root.String()
 if result != test.results[i] {
  t.Errorf("%s=(%q): got\n\t%v\nexpected\n\t%v", test.name, test.input, result, test.results[i])
 }
 
 
 
 
}
` its not working ...

Comment: Can you please provide some working example which I can use as reference to my context ?

Comment: @Nin I am on my phone today, so I won't be able to work on this answer, but you still have 24h after the bounty to decide. My answer was just a starting point for you to adapt.

Comment: in addition if we look on your example , how for productive shipped code you will test it . this is what im looking for , thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

yourcodefile.go

```
    type API map[string]string

    type data struct {
        File *File
        API  API
    }
    func DynamicdataForTemplate() data {
                    f := new(File)
                    f.Dependency = []Dependency{{
                        Name:    "ui",
                        Type:    "runner",
                        CWD:     "/ui",
                        Install: []Install{{"name": "api"}},
                    }, {
                        Name:    "ui2",
                        Type:    "runner2",
                        CWD:     "/ui2",
                        Install: []Install{{"name": "api2"}},
                    }}

                    datav := data{}
                    datav.File = f
                    datav.API = API{"runner3": "api3", "runner4": "api4"}

                    return datav
                }

 func ParseTemplate() error {
                    parsedTempl, err := template.New("t").Parse(tmpl)
                    err = parsedTempl.Execute(os.Stdout, DynamicdataForTemplate())
                    return err
}

    func main() {
        _ = ParseTemplate()
    }
```

---

use this Assertion Package for writing Test case 
https://github.com/stretchr/testify

yourcodefile_test.go

```
import (
    "testify/assert"
    "testing"
)


func TestDynamicdataForTemplate(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("should return the Type", func(t *testing.T) {
        dataType := data{}
        assert.IsType(t, dataType, DynamicdataForTemplate())
    })
}

func TestParseTemplate(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("should return the nil", func(t *testing.T) {
        assert.Nil(t, ParseTemplate())
    })
```

}

code coverage Report Command

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out
go tool cover -html=coverage.out
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, Can you please elaborate how should I check the real template , here you are checking the datatype which is OK but not sufficient...I need to check that the template is behave ok if I pass wrong parameters/data . Thanks!

Comment: you need to fake your `inputs`